# NotSerializableException when using Path in Jenkins DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-2

When I have the following in Groovy:

```
blub = Paths.get(pwd() + "/my/path")
echo blub.toString()
```

It prints

```
/jenkins/my/path
```

just fine.

But immediately after, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SerializableScript.writeObject(SerializableScript.java:26)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor235.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:132)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:452)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:427)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:415)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:360)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can someone make sense, why it works but still fails?

Comment: Does that path exists on the system?

Comment: Can you elaborate, why this would make a difference? And it fails regardless of whether the Path is there. Tried both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to wrap your Path operation in method marked `NonCPS`:

```
@com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
def test(String value) {
    // All Path operations here
    Paths.get(value)
```

Read gory details here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/#technical-design

Comment: While useful this does not address the case where you need/want to keep the UnixPath object.

Comment: You'd just need to make sure the whole method where you're using the UnixPath object is marked as NonCPS. The issue is that Jenkins isn't able to serialize the UnixPath object by default, which it needs to be able to do to pause/resume/do other fancy stuff with pipelines. Marking it as NonCPS instructs tells Jenkins not to even try any of the objects in that method.